# Why Internet is slow on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, internet

I've set up Raspberry Pi 3, installed Raspbian via NOOBS and connected to Wifi Network but the internet speed is extremely slow. On Laptops, PC and Mobile, speed is what it should be but on Pi, speed is almost none. I was able to open Google 1 or 2 times but not always.

Is the issue related to Raspbian's default browser?

Comment: I don't know.  Does it get better if you use a different browser?

Comment: It shouldn't be particularly slower.  If you do a `sudo apt update`, this should show a speed in kB/s and an average when completed, e.g. "Fetched 9,123 kB in 32s (285 kB/s)".   It doubt it will be much more than that because of internet bottlenecks and the nature of the transaction, but if it is significantly less, or stalls for a prolonged time, this will provide a clue as to whether it is the browser or the connection in general.

Comment: This may happen due to heavy UI that comes with browser.

Comment: The default browser on Raspbian for a Pi2 is quite slow for some things (probably in an attempt to reduce memory usage).  Some features don't work at all in some situations ("find in page" on a very long page, as partial loading/rendering is used is one that bugs me).  This can give the illusion of a slow link when actually the data is there but not being displayed. Firefox can be quicker if you don't open too many tabs.

Comment: You could also be hitting swap and maxing out swap space. As a test use wget on a known file that exists on the net, or as previously stated update and monitor the speed.